# How come there is no Course Rank for Spiral in Pac-Man CE DX?

Tags: pac-man-championship-edition-dx

I have Pac-Man CE DX for the XBox 360. On the course selection screen it displays an overall course rank for each course. However, the Spiral course does not have anything displayed in that area. Is it a bug? Is the Spiral course special for some reason?

Comment: +1 This happened for me as well, just thought something was messed up for me. Guess it's more wide spread than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Some PS3 users](http://www.giantbomb.com/pac-man-championship-edition-dx/61-32607/did-the-spiral-leaderboard-crash/35-468653/) have had problems with this also. It appears to be a game bug that affects a limited subset of users. [For other users](http://www.gamespot.com/xbox360/action/pacmanchampionshipeditiondx/show_msgs.php?topic_id=m-1-57225739&pid=997762&page=1), the course rank shows up correctly. I was unable to find a solution, or any offical developer comment on these issues.